# How to disable a button after click inside a Table in Ant design in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

How can I disable the following button after it is clicked inside a table in react in ant design.

```
<Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log('clicked');
          }} 
        >
          Resend
        </Button>
```

I don't want to set it to be disabled. I want the button to be disabled after the user click it.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by this? `I don't want to set it to be disabled. I want the button to be disabled` cause it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: After user clicked you mean the button must be one time clickable? you can set this in the `onClick` like `this.setState({ buttonDisabled: true });`

Comment: By this "I don't want to set it to be disabled. I want the button to be disabled" I mean that I only want the button disabled after it's clicked

Answer (score 1):

What version of React are you using? If 16.8+ then you could use a state hook to set disabled on click. [Here is a simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dq2jba?file=src/App.js)

```
  const [buttonEnabled, setButtonEnabled] = useState(true);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setButtonEnabled(false);
  };

  const resetHandler = () => {
    setButtonEnabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!buttonEnabled} onClick={clickHandler}>
        Button
      </button>

      <hr />
      <button onClick={resetHandler}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error, "Can't find these names, '!buttonEnabled' and 'clickHandler'. Also I'm coding in Typescript but the example you've posted is a js file. Thank you

Comment: The piece of code that I've posted is used inside a column in a Table from ant design.